# Principal value integral with cosine

Tags: integration, regularization

We are doing a practice set for an exam where we have to find the principal value of the integral

$$
I = P.V. \int^\infty_{-\infty} \frac{\cos(x)}{(x-1)(x^2+1)} dx
$$

Firstly, I am unsure if this converges?
I think it does, and so I tried using Jordans Lemma, finding the residues

$$
Res(i) = (-1/4 + i/4)cosh(1) 
$$
and
$$
Res(1) = \cos(i)/2
$$

Such that
$$
I = 2\pi i (-1/4 + i/4)\cosh(1) + \pi i \cos(i)/2
$$

But this seems wrong? Shouldnt the answer be Real?

Answer (score 2):

You are correct that it should be real, and indeed it is!

To see this, let's first expand $\cos(i)$ to get
$$\cos(i) = \frac{e^{i\cdot i}+e^{-i\cdot i}}{2} = \frac{e^{-1}+e^{1}}{2} = \cosh(1)$$
Thus,
$$\pi i \cos(i)/2 = \pi i\cosh(1)/2 = 2\pi i(1/4)\cosh(i)$$
and so the imaginary parts cancel out.

Comment: Thank you so much! That makes sense :)

Comment: @Sam Let $f(x) = \cos(x)/((x - 1) (x^2 + 1))$. Note that $\operatorname {Res}_{x = 1} f(x) \neq \cos(i)/2$ and $I \neq 2 \pi i \operatorname {Res}_{x = i} f(x) + \pi i \operatorname {Res}_{x = 1} f(x)$. We can however relate $I$ to residues of $e^{i x}/((x - 1) (x^2 + 1))$.